# html list value changes by key events

Tags: dom, dart

After starting the [Order](http://dzenanr.github.io/order/web/) game, change the game level from 1 to 2.
Use the left arrow key, the current value of the list goes from 2 to 1.
How can I avoid this change?

Key arrows (key events) are used in the game to move tiles. A select element (level) is used to change the size of the board. 
When a user changes the level and clicks on the new button, the key events do not affect the level. However, if a user changes the level (e.g., from 2 to 1) and then uses a key arrow (e.g., the left arrow key), the level changes (from 2 to 1). I want to disable that change.

I used unsuccessfully

```
document.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent event) {
  levelSelect.disabled = true;
  ...
  levelSelect.disabled = false;
});
```

in the Board class in the lib/view/board.dart file.

[Source code](https://github.com/dzenanr/order)

Comment: Can you please improve the question. The question should contain all relevant parts to be able to understand the question. Link to full code is fine but it shouldn't be necessary to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the select element to change the value the select element receives the focus (and takes it away away from the `body` element which has it after page load). The result is that the select element processes the key events instead the document where you registered your custom key event handlers.

Your attempt to set `disabled` to `false` and back to `true` would probably work with some use of Futures to allow the browser to process the state change.

A simpler solution is to make the select element remove the focus from itself using the `blur()` method:

```dart
levelSelect.onChange.listen((Event e) {
  levelSelect.blur();
  level = int.parse(levelSelect.value);
});
```